# Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public ViewResult Medicament(string searchTerm)
    {


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
           var Medicament = from s in db.MEDICAMENTs
                         from j in db.FOURNISSEURs
                         where s.ID_Fournisseur.Equals(j.CODE_FOUR) &&
                               j.NOM_FOUR.Equals(searchTerm)
                         select s;



             return View(Medicament.ToList().Any());
        }
                return View();
    }
```

I got this message:

Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `Equals` in this query. Use `==` instead. Equals(object obj) converts in expression that need to cast this obj to concrete type, but LINQ to Entities does not support such casting.

Answer (score -1):

It's a long time I don't write entity queries since my actual work company uses NHibernate. But I remember doing some queries like this:

```
public ViewResult Medicament(string searchTerm)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
    {
        var Medicament = from s in db.MEDICAMENTs
                     from j in db.FOURNISSEURs
                     where s.ID_Fournisseur equals j.CODE_FOUR &&
                           j.NOM_FOUR equals searchTerm
                     select s;

        return View(Medicament.ToList().Any());
    }

    return View();
}
```